# How do I choose between the Nikkor Z 26mm f/2.8 and Z 28mm f/2.8 (SE) for street photography?

Tags: nikon, mirrorless, street-photography

I recently purchased the Nikon Z7 II and got the 14 - 30mm ultra-wide. Now I am in the market for a street shooting lens (imagine seaside vacation etc.) and I am torn between the NIKKOR Z 26mm f/2.8 or NIKKOR Z 28mm f/2.8 (SE). What would be the best for sharp street shoots of holiday destinations? Please note that I am no professional - I will use it purely for my hobby and taking family photos.

To clarify so that this is not a specific what should I buy question: The look I want to achieve is natural cityscape in their natural environments. I do not want to be too close to the subject but rather focus on the *scene* itself. For example:

[This Rani Mani blog entry about Kenneth Hines that includes a number of his images](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2022/06/16/kenneth-professor-hines-teaches-and-inspires-through-photography)

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more precise about what exactly is stopping you from making a decision. What do you hope a 26/2.8 or 28/2.8 would offer you that your current lens doesn't? Right now, this is basically just a "which one should I buy" question, which, firstly, nobody can answer for you, and secondly, is off-topic. Also, remember to focus on the results and not the gear, if you know what I mean. None of these lenses is incapable of good photographic results, I'm sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the best for sharp street shoots of holiday destinations?

It doesn't matter. Photography (mostly) isn't about your gear, it's about your skill - and this applies double when you're talking about two very similar lenses like you are. The difference between 26mm and 28mm is mostly irrelevant.

Just buy one and go and improve your skills.

Comment: And either one is only one stop faster than the more flexible zoom OP already has.  Is that stop really important on a low noise camera?  I don't think so

Comment: @RossMillikan Unless the compactness and weight advantage of the 28mm pancake and, to a lesser extent, the 26mm f/2.8 are significant compared to the larger, heavier 14-30mm.